# How to break from middle of generator in dart?

Tags: dart, generator

How can I break from dart generator based on some condition?

```dart
fn sync*(...){
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  if(someCondition()) //cancel/break the generator
  yield 3;
  if(someCondition2()) //cancel/break the generator
  yield 4;
  if(someCondition4()) //cancel/break the generator
  yield 5;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply `return` from your generator when you want it to stop generating new values:

```dart
Iterable<int> fn(bool flag) sync* {
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  if (flag) {
    return;
  }
  yield 3;
}

void main() {
  print(fn(true).toList()); // Prints: [1, 2]
  print(fn(false).toList()); // Prints: [1, 2, 3]
}
```

Comment: LOL, for some reason, the linter forbid me from doing this before. Maybe I overlooked something.

Comment: @somebody4 Maybe because your syntax for declaring a generator function was wrong.  You omitted the return type and put `sync*` in the wrong place.